# How to modify datepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I was wondering if it's possible for the user to select dates that are 7days from the current date using the jquery date picker?

For example today is 2nd March 2015. The user can only select a date between the current date and 8th March 2015. Between 7 days. I want the rest of the days to be blocked

Thanks

Comment: research works: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

This is the info you need to limit date range between today and 7 days hence:

```
$('#dpFrom').datepicker({
    minDate: '+0d',
    maxDate: '+7d',
    dateFormat: "MM d, yy"
});
```

The `dateFormat` information is here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Here is a jsFiddle that demos the above, with some additional functionality that might be helpful:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLpspzLc/

If this solves your problem, please accept the answer -- but if it does not, please add comments below this answer and I will attempt to clarify further.